# iOS Safari and Mac OS Safari don't send cookies

Tags: angular, safari

I have an Angular 5 application that tries to load products over an HTTP-GET API call and crashes on iOS Safari and Mac OS Safari.

The first time I access the page everything works fine but after the second time my Angular application crashes because the HTTP-GET doesn't return the expected values.

I checked the developer console and it turns out that Safari doesn't send the cookies from my domain that are required for the GET to work.

[image]
It says that the Request came from the hard drive cache.
I checked the log files on my server and Safari actually calls my API (despite it saying it used the hard drive cache) but without the cookies.

The HTTP-GET from my Angular application looks like this:

```
this.noCacheHeader = new HttpHeaders()
              .append('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
              .append('Cache-control', 'no-store')
              .append('Expires', '0')
              .append('Pragma', 'no-cache');

get<T>(url: string): Observable<T> {
        return this.http.get<T>(this.baseUrl + url, { withCredentials: true, headers: this.noCacheHeader });
      }
```

I'm already disabling caching because of caching troubles with IE11.

What can I do to tell Safari to always send my cookies?

**Update 1:**

I added a ticks parameter to my HTTP-GET query "products?ticks=1337" and now it works. So it must have something to do with caching.

Comment: I had the same issue with Safari. I had to go to preferences -> privacy -> uncheck "prevent cross-site tracking"

Comment: Thank you @BradenBrown, in my case, this was the root cause of not sending cookies via the request.

Answer (score 2):

It may not be the same, but I had the similar issue with Safari. I was using `<audio>` tag inside the html loaded by jquery. Safari did not include cookies in the request for the audio source, therefore it did not load properly. But somehow it worked after I refreshed the page with CTRL+F5 - it sent cookies with this total reload...

I solved it by adding `crossorigin="use-credentials"`... Nasty problem.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a custom Http Interceptor:

```
// custom.interceptor.ts
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

intercept (httpRequest: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
  Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const clonedRequest = httpRequest.clone({
      withCredentials: true
    });

    return next.handle(clonedRequest);
  }
}
```

Then reference the interceptor in your `app.module.ts`:

```
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CustomHttpInterceptor } from 'your-module;

@NgModule({
  ...,
  imports: [
    ...,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: CustomHttpInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
  ],
})
```

`withCredentials: true` is the important part of the interceptor. Setting this option should pass cookies back on every request.

See: https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptions and https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-credentials for more information.

If you're already doing that, it's likely a caching issue. Try setting the `Cache-Control` header to be more restrictive:

```
setHeaders: {
  "Cache-Control": "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
}
```

or finally, append a querystring parameter to the request that is always unique, like a UNIX timestamp.

Comment: I updated my answer because I actually use "withCredentials: true" in my calls.

Comment: Gotcha. It does sound like a caching issue then.